# How to change 1 to 00001?

Tags: c#

I want to have numbers with a fixed digit count.

example: 00001, 00198, 48484

I can do like this:

```
string value;

if (number < 10)
{
    value = "0000" + number.ToString();
}
else if (number < 100)
{
    value = "000" + number.ToString();
}
else if (number < 1000)
{
    ...
}
```

But this is a bit odd. Is there any built in function for my purpose?

Comment: Ohh, How many solutions there are and I'm in the corner of the world!!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
string value = String.Format("{0:D5}", number);
```

Answer (score 23):

According to the MS reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

> You can pad an integer with leading zeros by using the "D" [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
>   numeric format string together with a precision specifier. You can pad
>   both integer and floating-point numbers with leading zeros by using a
>   custom numeric format string.

So:

> To display the integer as a decimal value, call its ToString(String)
>   method, and pass the string "Dn" as the value of the format parameter,
>   where n represents the minimum length of the string.

Code:

```
string value = number.ToString("D5");
```

.NET fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/0U9A6N

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `ToString()` method with custom formating - [see the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0).  In particular the `0` specifier.

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

eg,

```
value = number.Tostring("00000");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string value = number.ToString("00000");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way  :

```
number.ToString("00000")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to return 5 digits numbers, you should use the [PadLeft() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx);

```
int Value = 101;
char pad = '0';
String sValue = Value.ToString();

sValue  = sValue.s.PadLeft(5, char)
```

In this case, you don't have to test whether to add  1, 2 or 3 zeros, it'll automatically add the number of zeros needed to make it 5 digits number.

Answer (score 2):

```
int input_number = Convert.ToInt32(txtinput.Text);
string number_value = input_number.ToString("00000");
```

I hope that it will solve your problem. It worked well for me in my previous project.
Test this code in your development. It should be worked properly without doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Same as @Jojo's answer, but using [C# 6's interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings):

```
var value = $"{number:00000}";
```

Answer (score -2):

Apart from `String.Format`, You can also use [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx)

```
value = number.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
```

Comment: Why call 2 methods when your problem can be solved with 1 method call?!