# a = a + 00001 what i miss

Tags: c#, sql-server

Could you please help me to get a solution to my issue. I am using a SQL Server database, it is a Count button i us this code on it :

```
int a;  
using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("select * from voiceno WHERE ID = '1'", con))       
{
    con.Close();
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = command2.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        string val = dr[1].ToString();
        if (val == "0")
        {
            txtinvoiceno.Text = "00001";
        }
        else
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1].ToString());
            a = a + 00001;
            txtinvoiceno.Text = a.ToString();
        }
     }
}
```

and my table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[voiceno](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[voiceno] [nvarchar](50) NULL
```

**when i get the first recode it start with 00001 bout in the second recode gave me 2 (i need to make it 00002)**

Comment: `a.ToString("00000")`?

Comment: @RubensFarias do you mean ' txtinvoiceno.Text = a.ToString(00000);'

Comment: You have to differ between **data** (your number) and **presentation** (your string). You can of course caluclate with your data, however leading or trailing zeros are a formatting-thing.

Comment: Why do you close connection then open it after?

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026352/how-to-change-1-to-00001

Comment: Your code would break in the future if you alter the table structure, better reference the columns by name `dr["voiceno"]` instead `dr[1]`. Also it is way more readable

Comment: @bradbury9 ok i will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you need to do is just formatting: Here you are having an integer and you wanted to show them with prefixed zeros. You can make use of the overloaded [`.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to specify the format.

One more important thing you have to consider is the `FormatException`, See you have used `Convert.ToInt32()` for converting the value to integer, this won't be a good choice here as it will throw `FormatException` when the value of `dr[1]` is DBNull or empty, so I recomand you to use `TryParse()` instead. Have a look at the code below:

```
int.TryParse(dr[1].ToString(), out a);
a = a + 1;
txtinvoiceno.Text = a.ToString("00000");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PadLeft function

```
ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
```

or simply use format argument in `ToString` function like:

```
ToString("00000");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int i = 2;
  string s = i.ToString("00000");
//result will be 00002
```